# Google Java style: checkstyle file with corresponding editorconfig file for Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, checkstyle, editorconfig

There is checkstyle file for google java style.
https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml

I am looking for corresponding

> .editorconfig

file.

Comment: Afaik, this doesn't exist officially. However, the Checkstyle plugins for Eclipse and IntelliJ have import features that let you import a Checkstyle config, and they'll configure the IDE to match (within limits).

Comment: What about the Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0):

The same effect is to install extension https://github.com/jdneo/vscode-checkstyle

with the settings:

```
"java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
"checkstyle.enable": true,
"checkstyle.configurationPath": "config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml",
"checkstyle.checkstylePath": "C:/dev/tools/checkstyle-8.8-all.jar"
```

Now Visual Studio Code shows warnings in the code according to my checkstyle.xml file